# Underrated Music by John Williams | Which pieces of music by John Williams are critically acclaimed but have received very little popular attention?

Tags: soundtrack, history

John Williams is largely known for his *Star Wars* soundtrack.

He is critically acclaimed. Many people will recognise the "[Imperial March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bzWSJG93P8)" theme from *Star Wars*.

[You might find the song "Hymn to the Fallen" to be intense and/or emotional.]

I was listening to  "[Hymn to the Fallen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ejg-lPcFxU)," and I was wondering what other pieces of music were by him.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saving_Private_Ryan_(soundtrack)#Reception)

---

I managed to find some sources on this topic, but it would be very much appreciated if I could find general information from music sources written by [music critics](https://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/artist) about his underrated tracks.

(https://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/john-williams/266795/the-15-greatest-john-williams-scores-youve-forgotten-about)

Underrated, in this answer, is defined as: being critically acclaimed by professional critics but also having received very little popular attenion in the [Billboard Charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_charts).

---

**Direct Question**: What are examples of pieces of music by John Williams are critically acclaimed but have received very little popular attention attention?

---

**Prior Research**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_score)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Williams)
- (https://hotcorn.com/en/movies/news/5-criminally-underrated-film-scores-john-williams/)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_John_Williams)
- (https://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/john-williams/266795/the-15-greatest-john-williams-scores-youve-forgotten-about)

Comment: I have changed it from "songs" to "pieces of music." Thank you for your input!

Comment: I'm afraid, that neither *underrated* nor *very little attention* are precise enough for an authoritative answer and I have some doubts, that you get a per-piece quantification (neither on the acclaim nor on the popular attention side); therefore I voted to close the question as mostly opinion-based. I agree with PiedPiper, that it is a generic tendency covering many of his works.

Comment: See here: < https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_charts >. I've added this to the question.

Comment: Do we need statistics in the Music Fans website?

Comment: @guidot I appreciate your input. Let's work this out.

Comment: To really answer the question adequately someone would have to look at every single work, measure the critical acclaim objectively, measure the public attention objectively and then compare the two values.

Comment: You already answered the question. You mentioned "Memoirs of a Geisha." Just find a few songs similar to that. It doesn't have to be extremely pedantic.

Comment: Let's not enter extended discussion. I'm willing to cooperate with you to improve the question. Best wishes.

Comment: (https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/202/5380)

Comment: I want to post this as an answer, < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGLqYr-pUvM >, but the question is now closed. The song is relatively unknown. To contrast "Imperial March" has ~100,000,000 (at the time of writing) on YouTube.

Comment: 《Identification questions》 are no longer allowed. This controversy was closed by another member. The thread should stay locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of John Williams 'serious' works have received critical acclaim but they're virtually unknown to the general public, possibly because they are written in a more mainstream modern style in contrast to the romantic style of his film scores. He's written concertos for Flute, Oboe, Clarinet, Bassoon, Trumpet, Horn, Tuba, Violin, Viola and Cello, and about fifty other pieces including a symphony.

[Perspective: How much gold can lie in 45 Oscar losses? In the case of John Williams, the answer is: Tons](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/arts/la-ca-cm-john-williams-20180302-story.html)

Critics also have highly praised some of his less well known film scores e.g. ["Memoirs of a Geisha"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoirs_of_a_Geisha_(soundtrack))